# Getting the number of affected rows in FMDB updation query

Tags: objective-c, database, sqlite, fmdb

I am updating my table with FMDB. How can i get total number of rows that updated. 
(Actually i have an issue. My update query is returning "true", even i have no data in that table.)

Thanks in Advance. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
- (int)changes;
```

Used like:

```
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"store.db"];
if ([db executeUpdate:@"UPDATE xy SET ..."]) {
    NSLog(@"Did change %d rows", [db changes]);
}
else {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Great! Please also accept the answer (click the checkmark) so your question is marked as resolved. :)